# how to import py file from different upper folder?

Tags: python, path, import

All,

File structure:

```
\
util
  utils.py
modules
  __init__.py
  modules1.py
  submodule
     __init__.py
     submodule.py
```

I want to know how to import `utils.py` in those

```
__init__.py
```

for example, now I run the python interpreter in \ level, I run `import modules`, I suppose the code `from ..util.utils import *` may works, but it is not.

may I know where is the mistake? 
and may I know if there's a way i can import utils.py in a universal format?
something like

```
import \util\utils.py
```

I know I may use path.append(), but any alternative?

Thanks

============

got the answer from this post:

[Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: I seem, but can you explain why ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package occured in my case? I think the ..util.utils may point to the file i want by 1st intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developping a python **package** (what you are obviously doing, as you have **init**.py), then the most simple way to import your module is just via the package.
For example, if your package is called `mypackage`, then:

```
import mypackage.utils
```

Comment: thanks, but may be not a package but an application if I add a C-like main.py on the \ folder. So is you means i can pack all the codes to a folder then add another __init__.py? and move the init involing outside of this folder?